# Redis: Memory optimization for lists

Tags: list, memory, optimization, redis

I am trying to optimize memory usage for lists. After reading this [great memory optimization article](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) I forced the usage of ziplists to see the effect it would have but even though my RDB was reduced by 70%, the memory consumed by Redis was little reduced...

Here is some data about my instance:

```
# Memory
used_memory:28894160544
used_memory_human:26.91G
used_memory_rss:29423480832
used_memory_peak:28894160544
used_memory_peak_human:26.91G
used_memory_lua:33792
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.02
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0

# Keyspace
db0:keys=8433742,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

- The RDB file is **18GB**
- From those ~8.5M keys, ~6M are some control keys consuming only 700 MB of memory (I deleted all the lists once to check that)
- The remaining objects (~2.5M) are Lists that have from 1 to 75 items (and a few old lists with up to 500 items) corresponding to ~26 GB
- Each item is a JSON object (less than 1 KB)

I then, applied these settings:

```
list-max-ziplist-entries 1000
list-max-ziplist-value 10000
```

(I am aware that those are high and can be dangerous... I just wanted to guarantee to cover every list... Most lists have 75 items (and I will force them to keep that size) with less then 1000 bytes per item)

Resulting in:

```
# Memory
used_memory:26486158232
used_memory_human:24.67G
used_memory_rss:26687750144
used_memory_peak:26553209288
used_memory_peak_human:24.73G
used_memory_lua:33792
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.01
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0
```

- As you can see, around **2.2GB** reduction on the memory (**8.3%**)
- After running a BGSAVE under this configuration, my RDB file had **5 GB** (**72%** of reduction)

Furthermore, I debugged a few lists before and after to see what happened to them... Here goes some examples:

List A (75 items):

```
- Before:
Value at:0x7f0ab6b04940 refcount:1 encoding:linkedlist serializedlength:29332 lru:0 lru_seconds_idle:2623116
- After:
Value at:0x7f9b8a464920 refcount:1 encoding:ziplist serializedlength:8151 lru:0 lru_seconds_idle:2623697
```

List B (56 items):

```
- Before:
Value at:0x7f0e62d83270 refcount:1 encoding:linkedlist serializedlength:28797 lru:0 lru_seconds_idle:2623201
- After:
Value at:0x7f9ee1b9dfa0 refcount:1 encoding:ziplist serializedlength:4438 lru:0 lru_seconds_idle:2623692
```

LIST C (15 items):

```
- Before:
Value at:0x7f0c8fbdcfb0 refcount:1 encoding:linkedlist serializedlength:1160 lru:0 lru_seconds_idle:2623249
- After:
Value at:0x7f9d3852d330 refcount:1 encoding:ziplist serializedlength:720 lru:0 lru_seconds_idle:2623675
```

This gives me **72%**, **85%** and **38%** object reduction, respectively

Everything is taking a lot less memory, except what I want, which is the total memory consumed by Redis :(

---

So I have mainly 3 questions:

1. How can ziplists compress so much the RDB file but so little RAM usage?
2. What is exactly the serializedlength in the DEBUG OBJECT? Does it reflect only the size in the RDB? What about how much memory is that key consuming from my running instance?
3. Is that the most I can take from ziplists, or am I missing something? What else can I do (besides compressing the JSON data from the list items). I don't get how ziplists can be so effective for serialization but helping little with Redis memory footprint